# InsertRowsAtIndexPaths ,break at [_mainTableView endUpdates],but if I delete beginupdates and endUpdates,will break in SDAutoLayout

Tags: ios, insert, tableview

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

```
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    [_dataArray addObject:@"loading"];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [indexPaths addObject: indexPath];
    [_mainTableView beginUpdates];
    [_mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [_mainTableView endUpdates];
    
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  //  [_mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_dataArray.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}];
```

## pragma mark -UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
 (NSInteger)section
 {
  return _dataArray.count;
 }
```

Comment: will break in sdautolayout:       UITableView+SDAutoTableViewCellHeight.h                                                                                            
 - (void)sd_insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{
    [self.cellAutoHeightManager insertNewDataAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    [self sd_insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:animation];
}